# Getting the points of a filled ellipse in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, shapes

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction as to how I would generate the points of a filled ellipse or circle.

I know of algorithms to draw the outline, but not the contents as well.

All I require are an array of points. But I have no idea where to start and can't seem to find my answer on Google.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know the points of the outline, so you could just sort them by line (i.e. by the y-coordinate). When the two y-coordinates are equal, sort them by x-coordinate.

Now, for two points with the same y-coordinate you know that all points between them must be in the ellipse.

Comment: I have considered this, but I did not know how fast it would be. Worth a shot though. I will give this method a go as soon as I can and accept if it is feasible.

Comment: I have decided to not even try to draw ellipses because it would not be fast enough, no matter what the method was. So, if I was still going to use them I would probably use this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the points by scanline. The equation of an ellipse is

> *ax*<sup>2</sup> + *by*<sup>2</sup> + *c* = 0

So iterate over the values of *y* and solve for *x*. You'll get a quadratic equation in *x* with two solutions, giving you the points at the left and right end of the scanline. All the point in between are inside the ellipse.

If you want fast generation of the coordinates for the endpoints, see John Kennedy's paper, [A fast Bresenham-type algorithm for drawing ellipses](http://homepage.smc.edu/kennedy_john/belipse.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at some graphics library like jsDraw2d

```
http://jsdraw2d.jsfiction.com/
```

A more efficient method though is probably to use Javascript to generate SVG images but unfortunately Internet Explorer up to version 8 does not support SVG.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not what I'm looking for. All I need are the points, this draws directly. I need to handle the drawing part.